# Multiple grid-child in same grid-area

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to create a card which is pretty simple, and contains only an image, a paragraph and two buttons.
The card I want to create:

[image: card I want to create]

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <p></p>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

```
.container{  
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns:[img-start] 120px [img-end content-start] 1fr [content-end];
  grid-column-gap: 1.6rem;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto)
}
```

Then I place my buttons:

```
button{
  grid-column: content;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: [img-start] 120px [img-end content-start] 1fr [content-end];
  grid-column-gap: 1.6rem;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto)
}

button {
  grid-column: content;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <p></p>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

However, the buttons overlap and aren't next each other, so I wish to know if there's a way to place multiple grid-items in the sane grid-area and say that this area is like a flex-row wrapper?

*I would have used flexbox with some divs which wrapped the buttons, and assigned this div inside the grid-area, but I want to use grid to gain knowledge of this CSS property. So I wonder if there is a native grid way to do so?*

Comment: Grid layout is meant for evenly spaced items... on a grid. The layout you want in the image isn't really on a grid, so I think flexbox would make a lot more sense for what you are trying to do here. Flexbox is designed for this

Comment: I've created a running demo - a [stack snippet](//stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) - to help demonstrate your problem. Could you add some useful (demo/representative) content to more easily show the problem?

Comment: Your code does not match your problem description. The code provided shows buttons that are not overlapping, and that are next to each other. Do you have more code that you have not shared with us? See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note:** In production, I would use web-tiki answer, it is the *natural* way to do it.

However, you say that your purpose is to gain knowledge, so let's see an alternate way to get what you want, and in the line that you wanted to go.

Asign both buttons to the same grid cell, make the 40% of the available width, and use justify-self to place the second one to the right:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1.6rem;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto)
}

img {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

p {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.btn1, .btn2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  width: 40%;
}

.btn2 {
    justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/120x120/EEE/31343C" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed consequat justo mattis magna sagittis, ac varius erat porttitor. Vivamus mollis pulvinar lacus in dignissim. Nunc eu nisi vitae augue ornare volutpat.</p>
  <button class="btn1">Btn 1</button>
  <button class="btn2">Btn 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! 
This seems a nice solution, although there might be issues when the card width is strongly reduced and buttons may overlap again.

Comment: Yes, of course it is not the best solution, I know. However, the buttons being 40% of the width, they will only overlap if they have a minimum width. And you can always set the second column of the grid to be  width: minmax(150px, 1fr);

Answer (score 2):

As Chris Barr mentioned, CSS [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout) is useful when the content is evenly spread as columns and rows. In this case, You can use [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) as shown below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 150px;
}

.content {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://shorturl.at/aceI2" alt="" class="thumbnail">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem diam, egestas at ipsum nec, luctus molestie turpis. Proin tempus sagittis lobortis. Ut nec velit ac odio eleifend semper.
    </p>
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, it is indeed the best solution.
But as mentioned in my original question, I wanted to use grid property if possible.

Comment: Got it. In that case, Please go with web-tiki's or vals's solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid), you need to **add another column** to fit the second button.
The paragraph should span the 2 last columns and each button should have their own column like this :

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: [img-start] 120px [img-end content1-start] 1fr [content1-end content2-start] 1fr [content2-end];
  grid-column-gap: 1.6rem;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto)
}

img {
  grid-column: img;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

p {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.btn1 {
  grid-column: content1;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.btn2 {
  grid-column: content2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/120x120/EEE/31343C" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed consequat justo mattis magna sagittis, ac varius erat porttitor. Vivamus mollis pulvinar lacus in dignissim. Nunc eu nisi vitae augue ornare volutpat.</p>
  <button class="btn1">Btn 1</button>
  <button class="btn2">Btn 2</button>
</div>
```